# What is it mean by minting token?

Tags: tokens, ico, bsc, mint

I've created a BEP20 token and I can't figure out some steps, I've created for about 21000000 total supply of token and why should I mint token after creating it?

1. How much should I mint? How minted tokens are different from not minted ones?

Answer (score 2):

> why should I mint token after creating it?

If you want to increase the total supply at a later date. (See [Introduction to Supply and Demand](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/economics/11/intro-supply-demand.asp) [external link]. See also [Creating ERC20 Supply](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/erc20-supply).)

Another use of the `mint()` function might be to reward miners (see [Rewarding Miners](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/erc20-supply#rewarding-miners)), but since you've deployed on the Binance Smart Chain - which has a centralised set of 21 validators - there's no way for you to do that.

> How much should I mint?

That depends how much you want to increase the supply by.

> How minted tokens are different from not minted ones?

There is no difference.